# iphone dynamically add a section to a tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, settings

I have a tableview actings as a settings or preferences panel (see below).  The name of the setting (for example Address) is the header of the section the setting is part of.  My question is if I want to allow the user to add her own setting how should this be done?  I was thinking of adding a "+" button on a toolbar and having a modal view controller pop up asking for the new setting details.  My question is whether there is a way of adding the setting directly to the settings view instead of popping up a modal view controller.  So pressing the "+" would expand the the view shown below with textfields for entering the details for the new setting.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/634bb426be.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/634bb426be.png)

Comment: Is this a coding or a styleguide question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options.

You can, for example, set a flag when the "add" button is tapped and call `[tableView reloadData]`.

Or, you can use these methods in `UITableView`:

```
– insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
– deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
– insertSections:withRowAnimation:
– deleteSections:withRowAnimation:
```

Of course, the latter option is more suited to what you're trying to accomplish. See the [UITableView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information on the aforementioned methods.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about insertSections!